# detect/close excel message box via C# after macro invokation

Tags: c#, .net, interop, office-interop, excel-interop

I can invoke a VBA/Excel macro via C#. If the user (in my case a C# program) entered invalid values a message box appears. This is no problem as I can time out via C# and make a decision based on that (i.e. determine whether a message box appears). The problem is that excel does not close properly when a message box appears. I am using this code to close excel:

```
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(someSheet);
excelWorkbook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Everything closes but excel and the message box stay open. I there a way to close the message box from c#?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no easy or *nice* way to do this. If the message box is holding the focus (there is no user interaction in between or while the automation is running) you could always take the [Microsoft solution - SendKeys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259971/en-us).

Comment: excellent - excelApp.SendKeys("{ESC}"); actually does the trick. please post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully used [**the Microsoft solution**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259971/en-us) for an office automation software that i implemented. It is not *elegant* and it comes with prerequisites (the message box should be holding the focus and there has to be no user interaction while the automation is running), but it works - click the box away with the [SendKeys method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx)!

Comment: As you said, it is very important that the excel app has the focus for this to work. Do you reckon I can set the focus via C#?

Comment: If you have only one excel instance (again prereq.) you can [find the process and activate the window using SetForegroundWindow or ShowWindowAsync](http://blog.billsdon.com/2011/10/c-sharp-check-if-application-is-already-running-then-set-focus/). If you have more than one excel instance, then i would store the Excel instance PID on starting it and later use it to activate it. How to activate a running window: [Alternative 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/232649/Setting-Focus-on-an-External-application) and [Alternative 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x57y7863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879691/excel-hangs-at-the-point-where-the-message-box-asks-if-i-want-to-save-the-workbo).

Using

```
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false
```

avoids Excel App to create message boxes, allowing your app to handle it as you want it.